# Is there any numpy tricks to avoid for loops in this piece of code?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop, optimization

I have a following pice of code, which basically sets certain elements of a long numpy array to zero.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[[1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]], 
              [[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 3, 4]]])

aup = a + 2

b = np.array([[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [0, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7], [0, 1, 2]],
              [[3, 4, 5], [0, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7], [0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]],
              [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [0, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7], [0, 1, 2]], 
              [[3, 4, 5], [0, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7], [0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]],
              [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [0, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7], [0, 1, 2]]])

for i in range(3):
    for j in range(4):
        for row_t in range(a[0, i, j], aup[0, i, j]):
            for col_t in range(a[1, i, j], aup[1, i, j]):
                row = row_t%5
                col = col_t%5
                b[row, col, i] = 0
```

The main problem is the run time, which can be a lot because of the 4 for loops I have. Is there any numpy trick to avoid these for-loops and basically attain the same?

**Update**:

I think it all boils down to the following problem. First find the minimum of `a` and maximum of `aup` over axis 2, i.e.

```
min_a = np.min(a, axis=2)%5  \\ [[1 0 1], [0 0 0]]
max_aup = np.max(aup, axis=2)%5 \\ [[1 0 1], [0 4 1]]
```

Npw list all the element wise tuples that form between `min_a` and `min_aup`. with corresponding index element:

```
tuples = [[1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [0, 2, 1], [0, 3, 1], 
          [0, 4, 1], [1, 0, 2], [1, 1, 2]]
```

and set the elements of `b` at those tuples to be 0:

```
b[tuples] = 0
```

So, the entire problem is basically efficiently finding these `tuples`.

Comment: the intent isn't very clear here, what do you want to accomplish? The logic appears very bizarre

Comment: @Rob It's kind of complicated to explain the entire logic here, as this belongs to a larger chunk of a project I am working on. Basically the logic is to set certain elements of the array `b` to zero based on a defined scheme. And the scheme is applied to get the arrays `a` and `aup` and finally setting zero is achieved in the `for` loop. All I want to know is if there exists any numpy trick based on how arrays currently are. It might not be possible, but I just wanted to know just in case.

Comment: How do you expect to replace the logic if you can't explain it?

Comment: I think my update is quite clear in explanation. All I need is to recast two arrays in to update based on element-wise minimum and maximum, and I am asking if it is possible to do that efficiently.

Comment: so, it seems like you're struggling to break a larger problem into smaller sub problems.  Perhaps you should ask a question that is something like, "Given this list and this set of values, how can I do this process in numpy?".  Right now you're asking how to optimize a convoluted algorithm that is particular to a very narrow problem you're not putting much effort into explaining, and so you won't get much positive feedback on stackoverflow.  No offense, but it sounds like you just want someone to do your homework.

Comment: I'm not sure how you get from `min_a` and `max_aup` to `tuples`.  Especially how you ever end up with `[..., 2]`

Comment: You could stick it in `@numba.jit` and see if performance improves.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, here is a vectorized version of your loops. It explicitly uses the fact that `aup` is `a` plus scalar offset:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[[1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]], 
...               [[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 3, 4]]])
>>> 
>>> aup = a + 2
>>> 
>>> b = np.array([[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [0, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7], [0, 1, 2]],
...               [[3, 4, 5], [0, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7], [0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]],
...               [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [0, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7], [0, 1, 2]], 
...               [[3, 4, 5], [0, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7], [0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]],
...               [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [0, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7], [0, 1, 2]]])
>>> 
>>> b0 = b.copy()
>>> 
>>> 
>>> for i in range(3):
...     for j in range(4):
...         for row_t in range(a[0, i, j], aup[0, i, j]):
...             for col_t in range(a[1, i, j], aup[1, i, j]):
...                 row = row_t % 5
...                 col = col_t % 5
...                 b[row, col, i] = 0
... 
>>> b_loopy = b
>>> b = b0.copy()
>>> 
>>> i, j, k, _ = np.ogrid[:2, :2, :3, :0]
>>> 
>>> b[(a[0] + i) % 5, (a[1] + j) % 5, k] = 0
>>> 
>>> b_vect = b
>>> 
>>> np.all(b_vect == b_loopy)
True
```

For arbitrary `aup > a` it's a bit more hairy. The code below is slightly slower than the loop for small problem size, but scales much better, see timings at the end of this post.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[[1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]], 
              [[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 3, 4]]])

aup = a + np.random.randint(2, 5, a.shape)

b = np.array([[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [0, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7], [0, 1, 2]],
              [[3, 4, 5], [0, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7], [0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]],
              [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [0, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7], [0, 1, 2]], 
              [[3, 4, 5], [0, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7], [0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]],
              [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [0, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7], [0, 1, 2]]])

def setup(i, j, k, l):
    b = np.random.randint(1, 10, (i, j, k))
    a = np.array(np.unravel_index(np.random.randint(0, i*j, (k, l)), (i, j)))
    aup = a + 1 + np.array(np.unravel_index(np.random.randint(
        0, (i-2)*(j-2), (k, l)), (i-2, j-2)))
    return b, a, aup

def f_loopy(b, a, aup):
    b = b.copy()
    for i in range(b.shape[-1]):
        for j in range(a.shape[-1]):
            for row_t in range(a[0, i, j], aup[0, i, j]):
                for col_t in range(a[1, i, j], aup[1, i, j]):
                    row = row_t % b.shape[0]
                    col = col_t % b.shape[1]
                    b[row, col, i] = 0
    return b

def unwrap_indices(a, aup, shp):
    i, j, k = shp
    _, k, m = a.shape
    ij = np.array((i, j))[:, None]
    m *= k
    a = a.reshape(2, -1)
    aup = aup.reshape(2, -1)
    fst, snd = mask = aup > ij
    fsti = np.flatnonzero(fst)
    sndi = np.flatnonzero(snd)
    bthi = fsti[snd[fsti]]
    m2 = m + len(fsti)
    m3 = m2 + len(sndi)
    d = np.empty((2, m3 + len(bthi)), dtype=int)
    d[0, m:m2] = aup[0, fsti] - i
    d[1, m2:m3] = aup[1, sndi] - j
    d[:, m3:] = aup[:, bthi] - ij
    d[:, :m] = np.where(mask, ij, aup) - a
    d[1, m:m2] = d[1, fsti]
    d[0, m2:m3] = d[0, sndi]
    aa = np.empty_like(d)
    aa[:, :m] = a
    aa[1, m:m2] = a[1, fsti]
    aa[0, m2:m3] = a[0, sndi]
    aa[0, m:m2] = 0
    aa[1, m2:m3] = 0
    aa[:, m3:] = 0
    z = np.empty(aa.shape[1:], dtype=int)
    z[:m].reshape(k, -1)[...] = np.arange(k)[:, None]
    z[m:m2] = z[fsti]
    z[m2:m3] = z[sndi]
    z[m3:] = z[bthi]
    return aa, d, z

def embed_indices_flat(aa, d, z, shp):
    i, j, k = shp
    _, m = aa.shape
    A = np.ravel_multi_index((aa[0], aa[1], z), shp)
    A[1:] -= A[:-1] + np.einsum('ij,i->j', d[:, :-1]-1, (j*k, k))
    A1 = (((j+1)-d[1]) * k).repeat(d[0]) 
    A1[0] = A[0]
    A1[d[0, :-1].cumsum()] = A[1:]
    idx = d[1].repeat(d[0]).cumsum()
    A2 = np.full(idx[-1:], k)
    A2[0] = A1[0]
    A2[idx[:-1]] = A1[1:]
    return A2.cumsum()

def f_vect(b, a, aup, switch_strat=20):
    b = b.copy()
    A, D, Z = unwrap_indices(a, aup, b.shape)
    if D.sum() > switch_strat * D.size:
        for ai, di, zi in zip(A.T, D.T, Z):
            b[ai[0]:ai[0]+di[0], ai[1]:ai[1]+di[1], zi] = 0
    else:
        b.ravel()[embed_indices_flat(A, D, Z, b.shape)] = 0
    return b

from timeit import timeit

print(np.all(f_vect(b, a, aup) == f_loopy(b, a, aup)))
print(timeit(lambda: f_vect(b, a, aup), number=1000))
print(timeit(lambda: f_loopy(b, a, aup), number=1000))

b, a, aup = setup(40, 30, 10, 8)

print(np.all(f_vect(b, a, aup) == f_loopy(b, a, aup)))
print(timeit(lambda: f_vect(b, a, aup), number=1000))
print(timeit(lambda: f_loopy(b, a, aup), number=1000))
```

Sample output:

```
True                      # <- results equal
0.08376670675352216       # <- vectorized
0.062134379986673594      # <- loopy
True                      # same for larger problem size 
0.3771689278073609        #
8.375985411927104         #
```

Comment: This is elegant. Thanks a lot. Is there any way this method could be generalized to an arbitrary `aup`, instead of an offset of `a`?

Comment: @titanium not as concisely, but I'll give it a try.

Comment: @titanium Ok, I think I got it working, but it's not elegant or easy to read I'm afraid.

Comment: This functionally works, so thanks a lot for the effort. However, `f_vect` as is stands now is computationally a lot more inefficient than `f_loopy` (I tried timing function to see that), which beats the whole purpose of trying out the new method.

Comment: @titanium no worries. It's quite ugly anyway.

Comment: @titanium I've tuned the second case a bit. It's completely unreadable now but for larger problem size it gives a considerable speed up.

Comment: Great. Could you please explain me the idea behind this code in definition of `f_vect`: `if D.sum() > switch_strat * D.size`?

Comment: @titanium in NumPy conventional slicing is faster than advanced indexing. When the rectangles to zero out are large, this speed advantage offsets the penalty for the for loop, so we switch strategy hopefully near the cross over.

Comment: So, my efficiency is dependent on how wisely I choose `switch_strat` right? If yes, what criteria should I use to choose a reasonably good `switch_strat`?

Comment: @titanium It's completely empirical, I'm afraid. You'll have to experiment. The value I put, `20`, seems reasonable, but I didn't check very thoroughly, since I don't know your exact use case.

Comment: @PailPanzer, I tried with different `switch_strat` and seems like there is roughly +- 20% change in speed based on its choice.

Comment: @titanium The change depends on how far away from the cross over you are. Anyway, if you see a stable 20% difference in your use case then just pick a value that puts you on the good strategy, no need to find the exact crossover point, I suppose.

Comment: Yeah. BTW, although the code is really good for the test case, it crashes for something like `b, a, aup = setup(90, 90, 1000, 2000)`, and I was just trying with `print(timeit(lambda: f_vect(b, a, aup), number=1))`.

Comment: @titanium With a memory error, yes. If you really need that many patches, you'll have to chunk it - do the 2000, I don't know, perhaps 200 at a time?